# Working around an API which interprets requests from a website on behalf of users as an attack

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, http

I am creating an ASP.NET MVC website that uses a 3rd party API (web service) as a data source. It is read-only, and to date has been accessed by individuals using desktop applications (most in C#). I would like to consume this API using a web site in order to centralize information and give users historical information, automate certain repetitive tasks, and more easily allow sharing of information among users.

The desktop clients today experience throttling, and if you make repeated requests to the API using a client your IP will be throttled and/or banned. I think that if I made the requests to the API from my website, its IP would be banned the moment it saw any significant use.

Let's assume that I cannot work something out with the API owners. Probably the easiest way to work-around this problem is to do all of the API access using AJAX. When the user visits the website, he makes the requests to the API using AJAX then turns around and posts them to my website. I don't like this idea for multiple reasons-- first, it'll be slow, and second, I could not guarantee that the data sent to my website was genuine. A malicious user could, for whatever reason, send me bad information.

So I thought a better idea would be to establish a man-in-the-middle. The user would still be forced to make the AJAX request, but they would make it to a proxy or something else that I control, which would then forward it on to the real API and intercept the response so I could be a little more certain that the data I retrieved was genuine.

Is it possible to create such a "proxy"? What would it entail? I would like to do it using a .NET technology but I'm open to any and all ideas.

**EDIT:** It seems I caused confusion by using the word "proxy." I don't want a proxy, what I want is a pass-through that allows me to intercept the response from the API. I could have the client make the request and then subsequently upload it, but I don't want to trust client, I want to trust the API.

Let me explain this in shorter form. There is a client on a user's machine which can make a request to an API to get current information. I would like to create a website that does the same thing, but I am considering the possibility that the API web service may notice that while previously it was receiving ten requests for ten users from ten different IPs, it is now receiving ten requests for ten users from one IP and block that IP seeing it as a bot even though every request was kicked off by a user request just as it had previously. The easiest way to workaround this is to have the user make the request and then upload the response to me, but if I do that I am forced to blindly accept data from a client which is a huge no-no for any website in any situation. If instead I can place something that forwards the request along to the API preserving the IP of the user but is also capable of intercepting the response thereby proving that the data is authoritative, that would be preferred. However, I can't think of a software mechanism to do this-- it seems like it would need to be done at a different layer.

As for legal concerns, this is a widely used API with many applications and users (and there are other websites I have found using the API), but I was unable to find any legal information like terms of service beyond forum postings in the API's tech support section amounting to "don't make repeated requests, obey our caching instructions" etc. I can't find anything that would indicate this is an illegal or incorrect use of the web service.

Comment: It seems this third party web service wasn't intended to be used the way you wish to use it.  I don't see how a proxy, as you call it, will help as it will run into the same limitations - either too few IP addresses will get throttled/banned, or you would need one proxy IP address per active user (which sounds untenable).

Comment: I agree with @Moho. As for your initial idea, unless the API owner supports CORS you would not be able to do the cross domain AJAX call from your web page to their API anyway

Comment: Work something out with the providers of the web service you want to use.  If you cannot and proceed anyway you are at the very least violating their Fair Use terms and at worst stealing from them and thus engaging in a criminal activity.

Comment: @MikeGoodwin but if I had my theoretical request forwarder ("proxy" was a bad word choice on my part) described in my question hosted on my domain, the browser would not prevent the request. My question is really if it is possible to hijack an HTTP request made to my service, forward it to a 3rd party service making it appear as though it came directly from my client (not from my service) and intercept the response. Again, what I'm looking for is a solution where I know the result came from the 3rd party and was not fabricated by a client.

Comment: Though I no longer need an answer (because in practice the API does not behave as I feared) I am still curious if what I'm talking about is possible. Can you fool a naive web-service into believing you are someone else? Can you spoof the IP of someone else while still getting the service to respond to you and not to the other IP? Any imaginative ways to use the client's browser to accomplish this, assuming that your client allows it and this hijacking is done with the client's knowledge and consent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement your proxy. It wouldn't need to be AJAX though, it could just be a normal web page request that displayed the API results if you wanted.

Either way, in .Net you could do it using ASP.Net MVC. If you wanted AJAX, use a Web API controller action that implements the source API, if you want a web page, just use a regular MVC controller/action.

Inside your controller, you would just make a web request to the source, passing through the parameters.

In order to avoid throttling, you could cache the results of each request you make from your server (using the normal ASP.Net cache), so that if another client attempted to make the same request, or a similar one maybe, you could return the cached results instead of making another request to the API.

You would have to determine how long the results should be cached for, depending on how up to date the data needs to be in your client. E.g. For weather data, caching for an hour would seem OK. For more fast moving data it would have to be less. You have to strike a balance between avoiding throttling and keeping data fresh.

You could also intelligently fetch more data than you need at each request and then filter the result set that you return to your client. This could give you a better cache hit rate.

Comment: The good news was that after performing more research I found that there are other websites that utilize the API, and that throttling/banning is only done to clients of the API that don't obey responses detailing how long one should wait before making another request for the same information, or repeatedly making errant calls.

Comment: I am accepting @Mike 's answer because he clearly spent time writing an answer he thought would answer my question (though it's too basic-- these things I had already considered) even though it does not. I'm going to ask a separate question that will hopefully be easier to understand and to answer. Really, thanks Mike for trying when most of the others (like some commenters) refused for reasons that, at least to me, didn't seem to be their business (legality or ToS compliance is my responsibility). I think you deserve an accepted answer.